# Why is TextFormat.color not a Number?

Tags: actionscript, casting

```
var tf:TextFormat = myTextField.getTextFormat();
trace(typeof tf.color); // "number"
trace(tf.color is uint); // true
var myColor:uint = tf.color; // error: 1118: Implicit coercion of a value with static type Object to a possibly unrelated type Number.
```

Why?

var myColor:uint = int(tf.color); // works. But why do I have to cast it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Adobe's API reference:

```
color:Object
```

So *color* is type of Object, the second line traced out number as type because it was assigned by default or in code, but it does not necessarily mean that *color* can only be number. We can assign string type to color object as well, so type of *tf.color* can be a number or a String:

```
tf.color = "0x00ff00";
myTextField.setTextFormat(tf); // Change text color to green
```

If we compare the following two lines:

```
var myColor:uint = "0x00ff00"; // 1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type String to an unrelated type uint.
var myColor:uint = tf.color; // 1118: Implicit coercion of a value with static type Object to a possibly unrelated type Number.
// var myColor:uint = new Object(); // This line gives same 1118: Implicit coercion of a value with static type Object to a possibly unrelated type uint.
```

We can see that the compiler is complaining that it needs explicit instructions to perform the  conversion. From this point, we have enough reason to believe that the compiler is designed the way it is. Also notice that you can use constructor of *uint* or *int* to convert Object to number. *uint* and *int* are both derived classes of Object.

```
var myColor:uint = new uint(tf.color);
```

I hope this shed light.